# Handling Multitudes of Azure CD Release Stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

Please take a look at this screenshot that shows the current non-production deployment releases...

[image]

I will soon be supporting the rollout of hundreds of new clients with Production releases. This means this diagram is going to get considerably larger and maybe unsupportable if I plan unwisely.

What I want to ask is whether anyone else has been in this situation and dealt with it or failed miserably with it?

This key points I must maintain are:

- New Production Stages will be manually triggered Production deploys
- will go to different regions around the world. Running Stage
- deployments using Green/Blue deployment methodology. Is that possible in Azure Releases?
- Variable Management. Processes and Tools to ensure Variables are dynamic and can be client specific.
- Simplest methods employed for ease of use. No clutter or technical debt.

I have had the previous attempt at writing this closed because and I quote "Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. This will help others answer the question.". So I hope this time it can be answered.

Comment: You can check out [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops) for classic release pipeline. Classic CD pipeline supports manually triggering stages. But Yaml multiple stages pipeline have a better Variable Management and more deployment strategies using [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops). It also have the benefit of [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#insert-a-template) pipeline